# Query MS Access multiple condition (where)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this data :

[image]

*Week,Year,Value are in Number format

I am trying to get the average value of the last 5 weeks: 5,000 (i.e. 25,000/5)

So far I have this query

x= user input/get last week in the current year (current Week)
y= current date, in year

```
INSERT INTO RR5 ([ID],[RR5]) 
SELECT ID, ROUND((SUM(AMOUNT)/5),4) AS RR5  
FROM resultTable 
WHERE Years =" & y - 1 & " and Week > " & 52 - (x - 5) & " Group BY ID"
```

But, I can only get week 51 and 52. I need to put the additional condition to tell the compiler i need week > 50 year 2016 and week < = 3 year 2017.

```
Years = " & y & " and Weeknum < " & x
```

to get the Week 1 2 and 3.

I don't think I could put those 2 conditions in the same "where". How do I solve this?

Solution :

```
 INSERT INTO RR5 ([ID],[RR5]) SELECT ID, ROUND((SUM(AMOUNT)/5),4) AS RR5  FROM resultTable WHERE (Years = " & Y - 1 & " and WeekNum > 52 - (5-" & x & ")) OR ( Years = " & Y & " and Weeknum <= " & x & " ) Group BY ID
```

simply add parentheses on each condition and connect it with OR for the other condition.

Thank you for your support hope it helps anyone with same issue.

Comment: Please provide the full code, including any VBA, and include the field types.

Comment: Dots as data or just a fanciful post?  As others say, provide  more details to enable better assistance.

Comment: apologies, dots mean continuous data from 1-52.

Answer (score 0):

You're root trouble is caused by how you are storing your date data. Instead of Year and Week, it would be better to store this as an actual date. However, as a workaround you can convert the existing year and week to a date, and then use that in the where clause.

```
WHERE (CDate("1 JAN " & Year) + (Week - 1) * 7) > (CDate("1 JAN " & y) + (x - 1) * 7)
```

What this is doing is it will take each record you have and use the CDate function to turn it into 1 January of the given year. Because these dates are really stored as Double numbers where 1 corresponds to 24 hours, I then add to the 1 January date to find out what the first day of the week is for each subsequent week. `(Week - 1)` assumes that the first week starts on 1 January.

Now, you just use the same logic for the year (y) and week (x) provided by the user. The query will return anything that occurred later than the date the user specified.

Comment: Hi SandPiper, thank you for the input. I also think would be easy if we can use gregorian calendar. unfortunately, those data are from BW and originally it was defined with this format (example: 1#2016,2#2016,.. 52#2016,1#2017) for each week. (sorry im not native english but i think u get it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
INSERT INTO RR5 ([ID],[RR5]) 
SELECT ID, ROUND((SUM(AMOUNT)/5),4) AS RR5 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 5 *
    FROM resultTable 
    WHERE Years * 100 + WeekNum <= SelectedYear * 100 + SelectedWeek
    ORDER BY Years Desc, WeekNum Desc)
```

Comment: This will work if he wants only the last 5 rows. My impression was he wanted the user to input the starting year/week and get everything later than that. In this particular case, the user wanted the last 5 weeks. What if the user wants the last 8 weeks, though?

Comment: @SandPiper exactly, I need the starting week and everything later than that. but it will always last 5 weeks the only thing that change is the current week.

Comment: I'm confused. You wrote _I am trying to get the average value of the last 5 weeks_ - and that is what my solution provided. If the "current" week is neither the current week nor the last, just filter on this selected year/week. See edited answer, please.